# Why lambda capture by copy have the same address of an external variable

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I was checking some old code that I tried with lambda and I noticed.
If I specify the lambda capture as copy and modify the value inside it it will modify the variable as it was a reference.

```
void classV::setLambda() {
  r.setLambda([=]() {
      value = 100;
      v = 10;
      std::cout << &value << std::endl;
  });
}
void classV::executeLambda() {
    r.runLambda();
    std::cout << "NVAL: " << value << std::endl;
    std::cout << "NVAL: " << v << std::endl;
    std::cout << &value << std::endl;
}
```

Basically, this code is storing a lambda on an external object (class instance) and being executed there, I imagined that, specifying the capture as copy, when I tried to get the value of those variables those should not change.... as it was copied.

But, this is not the case, both value and v are 100 and 10.
Just to be specific, value is an static int of the class classV, and v is an int object attribute of the classV.

Why are those values being changed?, I checked the addresses inside the lambda and the executeLambda and they are the same, shouldn't it only happen if it was captured by reference? Probably I am missing something here.

Comment: According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda), "[=] captures all **automatic variables** used in the body of the lambda **by copy** and **current object by reference** if exists".

Comment: I'm not quite sure if cppreference is technically right about that, or if it's technically that the `this` pointer is getting captured by copy, but either way, it's not supposed to make copies of your instance variables or static variables.

Comment: @user2357112, yes, I actually read that, what actually makes me confuse is that line from cppreference "[=, &i]{}; // ok: by-copy capture, except i is captured by reference". If on both scenarios the result will be the same, when should I use reference if, at least on this example, both are having the same behaviour?

Comment: @user2357112 from my tests it really looks like the this is passed by copy, which copies the address of it. But if it was like that and the this was implicit, declaring a variable of the same name on the class that executes the lambda shouldn't generate name clash? I feel that the answer is probably simple, but I wanted some confirmation on how it should behave on this scenario. If the variable is declared on the same scope as the lambda, inside the function, the behavior makes sense

Comment: A lambda can capture local variables (by value or by reference) and/or `this` (always by value, but it doesn't make a difference as `this` cannot be assigned to anyway). In the example with `[=, &i]`, `i` is in fact a local variable (a function parameter). In your example, `v` and `value` are not local variables; they are either members of `classV` (accessed via captured `this`), or they are global variables (you don't show enough code to figure out which).

Comment: This is an interesting question, can you post a complete running code so we can try?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik they are attributes of my class, one is an static one and the other is an public variable. I imagined that those are captured from the this, but It creates some confusion on my mind as the function is executed on another class and it has a variable with the same name. Sure, if it is only the address and the this is on the scope of the class that create the lambda there should be no name clash

Comment: You appear to be asking questions about code you haven't shown. In the code you have shown, there are no name clashes (there are undeclared identifiers, but not identifiers declared more than once). If you would like help with a particular scenario, show code demonstrating that scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[=]` does copy by value, and you'd expect to have a different address for the local `value`.

However, C++ makes an exception of member variables. They are still accessed through `this`. So your code is equivalent to writing:

```
r.setLambda([=]() {
    this->value = 100;
    this->v = 10;
    std::cout << &(this->value) << std::endl;
});
```

And `this` is a pointer so it stays the same with copy-by-value.

A solution would be to write

```
r.setLambda([=,value]()
```

but you can't capture member variables.

**You'll have to write:**

```
auto valueCopy = value;
r.setLambda([=]()
    // ... use valueCopy here.
```

*My advice*: try to avoid **default capture** modes as you'll get bit one day with unexpected or forgotten behavior.

Comment: You can now actually capture member vars by copy but its not that pretty: `[value=this->value](){}`